# Conditionaly render input field on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I can't figure out what it is I am doing wrong with this code. I would like to only render the Service_Account__c.CM_Service__c field based upon the value of the checkbox field Service_Account__c.To_be_used__c.

As it is now, the CM_Service__c field will never render, regardless of what values I put into the logic true or false.

```
<apex:pageblocksection title="Settings (If Applicable)" showheader="true" columns="1" >
     <apex:inputfield value="{!Service_Account__c.To_be_used__c}" required="false"> 
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="SERV" />                    
     </apex:inputField>

     <apex:inputfield id="SERV" value="{!Service_Account__c.CM_Service__c}" required="false" rendered="{IF(!Service_Account__c.To_be_used__c == true,true,false)}" />                         
</apex:pageblocksection>
```

Any ideas ? Is it just a syntax error I'm not catching...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rerender the parent element with conditionally rendered elements

```
<apex:pageblocksection id="rerenderme" title="Settings (If Applicable)" 
       showheader="true" columns="1" >
     <apex:inputfield value="{!Service_Account__c.To_be_used__c}" required="false"> 
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="rerenderme" />                    
     </apex:inputField>

     <apex:inputfield id="SERV" value="{!Service_Account__c.CM_Service__c}" 
       required="false"rendered="{!Service_Account__c.To_be_used__c}" />                         
</apex:pageblocksection>
```

And your rendered attribute can be shortened to just the field value (also fixing the improper `IF` which was written incorrectly but was not needed anyway)

Comment: Thank you very much. Do the two fields need to be part of the same block section in order for the rerender to work ?

Comment: @Zoom_v - No, just the same form